# Cannot recreate NanoStringNorm example plots from example codes

Tags: r

I have to work with NanoString data and I wanted to learn this R package called NanoStringNorm but somehow the example codes that are given, do not yield the same results as those displayed. I was wondering if I'm doing something basic very wrong or is their a discrepancy between the given code and the plots in this [introductory file](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NanoStringNorm/vignettes/NanoStringNorm_Introduction.pdf)

Comment: Which example shows different results? What are theses differences?

Comment: @sgibb : The ICC plot on page 23 of the hyperlink above, is totally different from the plot that I get when I run that code (have to add 'histogram =TRUE' in it). Also, the static plotting plots are different when a PDF is generated vs when the images are generated.

Comment: I don't know the package but you will possible get more attention if you will post the example code the desired result and your result.